# Install of Pod::Spell failing on Strawberry Portable 5.20.2

Tags: perl, perl-critic, cpanm

When I try to `cpanm Pod::Spell` on Strawberry 5.20.2 (64bit PortableZIP edition), it flags `I18N::Langinfo` as a dependency.  When it tries to download the distribution for `I18N::Langinfo` it locates it in `R/RJ/RJBS/perl-520.0.tar.gz` and, wisely, thinks better of continuing.

`Pod::Spell` is of interest only as a dependency of `Perl::Critic`.

Any suggestions as to how to untangle this dependency issue?

Comment: why don't you have I18N::Langinfo installed?  or if you do, why isn't cpanm finding it?

Comment: @ysth Mighty fine questions both.  I've re-downloaded the zip file & Langinfo does not seem to exist.

Comment: Hmm, `I18N::Langinfo` does not seem to be installed in ActiveState 5.20.1.  And I didn't find a copy in the Strawberry 5.20.2 Portable w/ extra PDL libs either...

Comment: probably it just doesn't work on MSWin so isn't built there.  maybe cygwin has it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting. I looked for [I18N::Langinfo](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blob?f=ext/I18N-Langinfo/Langinfo.xs) on my self-built Perl on Windows, and it is not installed either. I would have expected it to be installed so that it could croak:

```
croak("nl_langinfo() not implemented on this architecture");
```

It seems to me the problem is not Strawberry or ActiveState specific (because I am building from source). It maybe worth building the current blead, and if `I18N::Langinfo` is still not being installed, reporting this as a bug to p5p.

Now, even if you could install the module however, I would not expect it to work with a non-Cygwin `perl` on Windows. Therefore, if `Pod::Spell` really depends on the module, it wouldn't work properly anyway.

But, frankly, looking at the code for `Pod::Spell` it is not immediately obvious to me why it should depend on `I18N::Langinfo`.

Therefore, I switched to `cpanm`s work directory for `Pod::Spell`, and an `nmake test` (in your case, this would be `dmake test` with Strawberry Perl):

```
# *** WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING WARNING ***
#
# The following REQUIRED prerequisites were not satisfied:
#
# I18N::Langinfo is not installed (any version required)
#
t\00-report-prereqs.t .. ok
t\basic.t .............. ok
t\debug.t .............. ok
t\get-stopwords.t ...... ok
t\text-block.t ......... ok
t\utf8.t ............... ok
All tests successful.
Files=7, Tests=24,  9 wallclock secs ( 0.13 usr +  0.02 sys =  0.14 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

Therefore, I went ahead, and installed the module using `nmake install` (in your case `dmake install`).

`podspell` seemed to work.

But, IMHO, you are better off just using `aspell` as in:

```
C:\...> aspell --mode=perl lib\Pod\Spell.pm
```

[image: aspell spell checking Pod::Spell]

Note: I am using Aspell 0.60.6.1 installed using Cygwin.

Comment: My motivation for wanting to install `Pod::Spell` is because it is a dependency of `Perl::Critic`.  `Aspell` may be slightly more work than I need in this specific case.  ;)

Comment: dolmen added the dependency to the `podspell` in the last release, Pod::Spell does not depend on it, but I didn't closely enough check his work and so the dependency made it to the global dependency list. Installing the previous version or next version will work

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug that Pod::Spell depends on this module, I didn't carefully enough check someone else's patch in the last release. I temporary fix would be to install the previous release as the only real changes in this release were to `podspell` and not the whole module. It will be fixed in the future.

Comment: Before trying Sinan's make-install-dispite-make-test solution, I did try to specifically install prior version numbers by distribution path.  I'd assumed your CPAN directory was the correct one.  The current distribution is the only one I saw in your directory.  Is it available elsewhere?

Comment: I see http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/X/XE/XENO/Pod-Spell-1.16.tar.gz and (from a year ago) http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/X/XE/XENO/Pod-Spell-1.15.tar.gz.  Older versions are at http://backpan.perl.org/authors/id/X/XE/XENO/

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/Pod::Spell all versions can be found on metacpan, but yeah 1.15 is still published and cpanm can be used to install a specified version